# Get path to "linked file" added to a folder in a project of executable app?

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I have a utility win forms app which has a folder in the project to hold a text file to be modified.
This text file is located elsewhere in source and added to that folder as a linked file, to keep it synced with another project's needs.

The app needs to simply locate this file, open it, append a line and save it back.

How can I get the path to that linked file to simply use the File.AppendAllText() method to add my data?

Comment: Assuming you mean that the project references a file outside of the project directory, then you can't access that file at runtime, because the project link is only a compile time thing. If you copy the file to a known place, you will be able to access it. If not, you can't guarantee the file will exist, if you copy the application to another machine for example.

Comment: understood. this application will not be copied to another machine. it's simply a utility app that i use personally and am in complete control of.

that said, i think this simply won't work the way i'd like it to

Comment: No, like I said, projects (and their linked file information) only exist at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/SomeFolder/SomeFile.txt");
```

OR
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/SomeFolder/SomeFile.txt"); //if you are inside a Web Page or Controller in MVC

Considering that this file is there inside the project. where "~/" is the root folder of the project.